# How to detect if my directive is visible in AngularJS 1.6+?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have directive which display some table of elements.

```
<my-list ng-if="showList" items="someItems"></my-list>
```

I want to execute code always when my directive spears on screen. This code should update rows of my table.

I tried:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.$watch(attrs.ngIf, function(val){

    });
}
```

but this triggers code only once, after document load. Further showing and hiding does not trigger anything.

How can I execute code after showing directive?

Comment: Can you post the code in $watch?

Comment: How do you assign showList ?